# How to change UIButton HighLight Color using Monotouch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uibutton

How to change UIButton HighLight Color using Monotouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this, you will need to create a highlighted image for the button then use:

```
btn.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Images/btnHighlighted.png"), UIControlState.Highlighted);
```

Comment: I want to change highlight color, not a background image.Is there an solution?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to do this. You must subclass UIButton and draw it your self when is is highlighted. This is a simple example:

```
public class CustomButton : UIButton
{

    public CustomButton(RectangleF frame)
    {

        this.Frame = frame;
        this.AddObserver(this, new NSString("Highlighted"), NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);

    }

    public override void ObserveValue (NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context)
    {
        if (keyPath.ToString() == "Highlighted")
        {
            this.SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }

    public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

        if (this.Highlighted)
        {
            // Draw for highlighted

        } else
        {

            // Draw for normal

        }
    }

}
```

I have translated this from this question, which has an Objective-C example: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022763/change-background-color-of-uibutton-when-highlighted)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my previos anwser to post so check link that i already implemented [UIButton HighLigh Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733213/how-to-change-background-color-of-uibutton-in-monotouch/11753717#11753717)