# How to change the background color of a UIButton while it's highlighted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

At some point in my app I have a highlighted `UIButton` (for example when a user has his finger on the button) and I need to change the background color while the button is highlighted (so while the finger of the user is still on the button).

I tried the following:

```
_button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But it is not working. The color remains the same. I tried the same piece of code when the button is not highlighted and it works fine. I also tried calling `-setNeedsDisplay` after changing the color, it didn't have any effect.

How to force the button to change the background color?

Comment: Check this post https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/uibutton-backgroundcolor-for-uicontrolstateselected/ and this pod https://github.com/GabrielMassana/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS

Answer (score 445, accepted):

You can override `UIButton`'s `setHighlighted` method.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x387038);
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5bb75b);
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0 and Swift 4.1**

```
override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        super.isHighlighted = isHighlighted
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. It is kind of nice way to do this. Because you can define several similar buttons.

Comment: Just a newbie question, where would you subclass that button method? If I have a button in a view controller named ConversionViewController, how would I setup the button to change the background color when highlighted or tapped?  Would I subclass the setHIghlighted in the COnversionViewController?

Comment: So there is one problem with this answer that I found. 

If you want to have the same color be available when you select theButton then setHighlighted gets called after setSelected and thus will override any selected styling you have. The solution above might be better if you want to select the button as well

Comment: Here is the problem - what if you need a few buttons of different color? Say, 1st is green when highlighted, 2nd is red and so on. You'll need to create a new class for each case.

Comment: @YakivKovalskiy assuming you're using a sub-class, you could add two UIColor properties e.g. normalBackground and highlightedBackground, then assign self.backgroundColor = normalBackground or highlightedBackground accordingly. Don't forget to add an init method for ease of use e.g. initWithBackground:highlightedBackground:

Comment: To expand on @SK. 's addition, these properties could also be made IBInspectable so that you could do all the init through IB.

Comment: Should it be willSet instead of didSet?

Comment: Nice solution, just one suggestion: `backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? .lightGray : .white`

Comment: Works for `isSelected` as well

Comment: Why nobody had mentioned that the setter is being called only when you tap the button, but not during the initial layout! So by default there is no colour until you touch the button. So to make it work you also need to explicitly call `isHighlighted = false` somewhere in the beginning (on inititialization for instance).

Comment: So, for Objective-C. We must subclass UIButton to achieve this effect, right?

Answer (score 307):

Not sure if this sort of solves what you're after, or fits with your general development landscape  but the first thing I would try would be to change the background colour of the button on the touchDown event.

**Option 1:**

You would need two events to be capture, UIControlEventTouchDown would be for when the user presses the button. UIControlEventTouchUpInside and UIControlEventTouchUpOutside will be for when they release the button to return it to the normal state

```
UIButton *myButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 20.f)];
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[myButton setTitle:@"click me:" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"changed" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHighlight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonNormal:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Option 2:**

Return an image made from the highlight colour you want. This could also be a category.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
   CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return image;
}
```

and then change the highlighted state of the button:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Add UIControlEventTouchUpOutside and UIControlEventTouchCancel to buttonHighlight: event list and it will work always.

Comment: Option two is the best that I have found so far. I guess, however, that storyboards do have their advantages in this case!

Comment: Answer by Thomas is better and that's what I use also

Comment: If you're using `layer.cornerRadius` and go with option #2, you'll need to make sure to set `clipsToBounds` to true to get the image's corners rounded as well.

Comment: If someone stops by and needs an answer in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600980/how-do-i-set-uibutton-background-color-forstate-uicontrolstate-highlighted-in-s/30604658#30604658

Comment: Put the imageWithColor method in singleton, and use it so many times in many projects. Big help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here's a simple CocoaPod that makes images with colors, and also allows you to make resizable images with a corner radius and color: https://github.com/mxcl/UIImageWithColor

Comment: If you do not fell like writing a new method just to generate an image you can also use [CIImage imageWithColor:]

Comment: Just want to document my finding on iOS 13.3.1. Having `setBackgroundImage:forState` above in a `layoutSubviews` makes the system loops infinitely on `layoutSubviews` when dark mode is changed from control center. Moving it into `traitCollectionDidChange` solves the problem.

Answer (score 100):

There is no need to override `highlighted` as computed property. You can use property observer to trigger background color change:

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = highlighted ? UIColor.lightGrayColor() : UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.lightGray : UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used functionality like this. Can you explain where this goes? Is it in the IBAction buttonPress function or in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: What if I have multiple UIButtons with different colors?

Comment: @Dave G, you create a new subclass of UIButton by clicking `File>New>File>Cocoa Touch Class` and setting it to `subclass of UIButton`. Name the file for ex `CustomButton`, which will become both the file name and the class name. Inside this file, put the `override var highlighted` code shown above. Last step, set the UIButton on Interface Builder to use this `CustomButton` subclass by going to the Property page where it says "Custom Class" and has a dropdown box. It will say "UIButton" in grey letters. The dropdown list should show CustomButton. Select this, and the button is now subclassed.

Comment: Why nobody had mentioned that the setter is being called only when you tap the button, but not during the initial layout! So by default there is no colour until you touch the button.

Comment: So to make it work you also need to explicitly call `isHighlighted = false` somewhere in the beginning (on inititialization for instance).

Answer (score 55):

An handy generic extension in Swift:

```
extension UIButton {
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forUIControlState state: UIControlState) {
        self.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color), forState: state)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
extension UIButton {
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.fill(rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, for state: UIControlState) {
        self.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: color), for: state)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48):

In Swift you can override the accessor of the highlighted (or selected) property rather than overriding the setHighlighted method

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return super.highlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
            else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
            super.highlighted = newValue
        }
    }
```

Comment: This totally works, but I'm confused how you were able to figure this out? The parameters aren't in the documentation or UIButton.h as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is the swift syntax which emulates the behavior of overriding setHightlighted in objective c.   See documentation on Computed Properties here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: In swift you could use didSet

Comment: I have added example with property observer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29186375/195173.

Comment: I think what @shimizu was asking was how did you know `highlighted` was a property on UIButton. The answer is that it is a property on UIControl which UIButton inherits from.

Answer (score 29):

Override highlighted variable.
Adding `@IBInspectable` makes you edit the highlighted backgroundColor in storyboard, which is nifty too.

```
class BackgroundHighlightedButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var highlightedBackgroundColor :UIColor?
    @IBInspectable var nonHighlightedBackgroundColor :UIColor?
    override var highlighted :Bool {
        get {
            return super.highlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                self.backgroundColor = highlightedBackgroundColor
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = nonHighlightedBackgroundColor
            }
            super.highlighted = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Solution for **Swift 3+** without subclassing.

```
extension UIButton {
  func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, for state: UIControlState) {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: state)
  }
}
```

With this extension it's easy to manage colors for different states and it will fade your normal color automatically in case highlighted color is not provided.

```
button.setBackgroundColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Nice, this works great in Swift 5 as well.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer because it is exactly what is missing from the API.  It's analogous to the existing setTitle(for:).  It should be the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 25):

a more compact solution (based on **@aleksejs-mjaliks** answer):

**Swift 3/4+**:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? .lightGray : .white
    }
}
```

Swift 2:

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = highlighted ? UIColor.lightGrayColor() : UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

If you don't want to override, this is an updated version of **@timur-bernikowich**'s answer (**Swift 4.2**):

```
extension UIButton {
  func setBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor, forState controlState: UIControl.State) {
    let colorImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)).image { _ in
      color.setFill()
      UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)).fill()
    }
    setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: controlState)
  }
}
```

Comment: @FedericoZanetello this will override isHighlighted in all the buttons in your app, which isn't a good solution in my opinion. ill go with Timur's answer.

Answer (score 14):

UIButton extension with **Swift 3+** syntax:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
    }}
```

Use it like:

```
YourButton.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.white, forState: .highlighted)
```

Original Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604658/3659227

Answer (score 10):

Here's an approach in Swift, using a UIButton extension to add an IBInspectable, called highlightedBackgroundColor. Similar to subclassing, without requiring a subclass.

```
private var HighlightedBackgroundColorKey = 0
private var NormalBackgroundColorKey = 0

extension UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var highlightedBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &HighlightedBackgroundColorKey) as? UIColor
        }

        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                &HighlightedBackgroundColorKey, newValue, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
        }
    }

    private var normalBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &NormalBackgroundColorKey) as? UIColor
        }

        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                &NormalBackgroundColorKey, newValue, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
        }
    }

    override public var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if !highlighted {
                normalBackgroundColor = backgroundColor
            }
        }
    }

    override public var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if let highlightedBackgroundColor = self.highlightedBackgroundColor {
                if highlighted {
                    backgroundColor = highlightedBackgroundColor
                } else {
                    backgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: For swift 2.0, you will need to update the call to objc_setAssociatedObject to use an enum: objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                &NormalBackgroundColorKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)

Comment: Definitely best way in Swift if you want to keep it all in Storyboard.

Comment: I prefer using subclass not extension as this will affect the whole app

Answer (score 9):

You can use this category which add the method **setBackgroundColor:forState:**

https://github.com/damienromito/UIButton-setBackgroundColor-forState-

Comment: Huge advantage that it doesn't require subclassing.

Answer (score 7):

### Details

- Xcode 11.1 (11A1027), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    func createOnePixelImage() -> UIImage? {
        let size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        context.setFillColor(cgColor)
        context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}

extension UIButton {
    func setBackground(_ color: UIColor, for state: UIControl.State) {
        setBackgroundImage(color.createOnePixelImage(), for: state)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
button.setBackground(.green, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE:

Use the [UIButtonBackgroundColor](https://github.com/acani/UIButtonBackgroundColor) Swift library.

OLD:

Use the helpers below to create a 1 px x 1 px image with a grayscale fill color:

```
UIImage *image = ACUTilingImageGray(248/255.0, 1);
```

or an RGB fill color:

```
UIImage *image = ACUTilingImageRGB(253/255.0, 123/255.0, 43/255.0, 1);
```

Then, use that `image` to set the button's background image:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

#### Helpers

```
#pragma mark - Helpers

UIImage *ACUTilingImageGray(CGFloat gray, CGFloat alpha)
{
    return ACUTilingImage(alpha, ^(CGContextRef context) {
        CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, gray, alpha);
    });
}

UIImage *ACUTilingImageRGB(CGFloat red, CGFloat green, CGFloat blue, CGFloat alpha)
{
    return ACUTilingImage(alpha, ^(CGContextRef context) {
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, red, green, blue, alpha);
    });
}

UIImage *ACUTilingImage(CGFloat alpha, void (^setFillColor)(CGContextRef context))
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, alpha == 1, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    setFillColor(context);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Note: `ACU` is the class prefix of my Cocoa Touch Static Library called Acani Utilities, where AC is for Acani, and U is for Utilities.

Answer (score 5):

Try this !!!!

For TouchedDown Event set One color  and for TouchUpInside set the other.

```
- (IBAction)touchedDown:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Touched Down");
    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}

- (IBAction)touchUpInside:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"TouchUpInside");
    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];    
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. I just had to add `- (IBAction)onButtonTouchDragOutside:(UIButton *)sender {` to make sure the colour doesn't remain on when the user accidentally drags his finger off the button.

Answer (score 5):

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControl.State) {
        let size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.fill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
    }

}
```

**Swift 5** , thanks @Maverick

Answer (score 5):

simple is that use that UIButton Extension ONLY

```
extension UIButton {

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControl.State) {
        self.clipsToBounds = true  // add this to maintain corner radius
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
            let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
        }
    }

}
```

and use this

```
 optionButton.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.42, blue:0.82, alpha:1.0), forState: .selected)

 optionButton.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.96, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0), forState: .highlighted)

 optionButton.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.96, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0), forState: .normal)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5, iOS 15+**

Since iOS 15 you can use a new UIButton API to configure button appearance.

The system **will automatically fade your button's background color** when it is tapped. You don't need to add any additional code for it.

```
var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .systemBlue
configuration.baseForegroundColor = .white // used for title color
configuration.title = "My button"
configuration.buttonSize = .large
let myButton = UIButton(configuration: configuration)
```

If you want your button to change background color on tap to some **custom color**, add this:

```
let configHandler: UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler = { button in
    switch button.state {
    case .highlighted:
        configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .systemRed
    default:
        configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
}
myButton.configurationUpdateHandler = configHandler
```

There is a great article on topic: https://sarunw.com/posts/dynamic-button-configuration/

Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked. If the questions are exact duplicates of each other, please vote/flag to close instead.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I removed the duplicate answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Subclass the UIButton and add inspectable properties for convenient use (written in Swift 3.0):

```
final class SelectableBackgroundButton: UIButton {

    private struct Constants {
        static let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.1
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var animatedColorChange: Bool = true

    @IBInspectable
    var selectedBgColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)

    @IBInspectable
    var normalBgColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if animatedColorChange {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(Constants.animationDuration) {
                    self.backgroundColor = self.selected ? self.selectedBgColor : self.normalBgColor
                }
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = selected ? selectedBgColor : normalBgColor
            }
        }
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if animatedColorChange {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(Constants.animationDuration) {
                    self.backgroundColor = self.highlighted ? self.selectedBgColor : self.normalBgColor
                }
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = highlighted ? selectedBgColor : normalBgColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass the UIButton and make a nice forState.

**colourButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface colourButton : UIButton

-(void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor forState:(UIControlState)state;

@end
```

**colourButton.m**

```
#import "colourButton.h"

@implementation colourButton
{
    NSMutableDictionary *colours;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    // If colours does not exist
    if(!colours)
    {
        colours = [NSMutableDictionary new];  // The dictionary is used to store the colour, the key is a text version of the ENUM
        colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", UIControlStateNormal]] = (UIColor*)self.backgroundColor;  // Store the original background colour
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    // If it is normal then set the standard background here
    if(state & UIControlStateNormal)
    {
        [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    }

    // Store the background colour for that state
    colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", state]]= backgroundColor;
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    // Do original Highlight
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    // Highlight with new colour OR replace with orignial
    if (highlighted && colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", UIControlStateHighlighted]])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", UIControlStateHighlighted]];
    }
    else
    {
        self.backgroundColor = colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", UIControlStateNormal]];
    }
}

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    // Do original Selected
    [super setSelected:selected];

    // Select with new colour OR replace with orignial
    if (selected && colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", UIControlStateSelected]])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", UIControlStateSelected]];
    }
    else
    {
        self.backgroundColor = colours[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", UIControlStateNormal]];
    }
}

@end
```

**Notes** (This is an example, I know there are problems and here are some)

I have used an NSMutableDictionay to store the UIColor for each State, I have to do a nasty text conversion for the Key as the UIControlState is not a nice straight Int.  If it where you could init an Array with that many objects and use the State as an index.

Because of this you many have difficulties with e.g. a selected & disabled button, some more logic is needed.

Another problem is if you try and set multiple colours at the same time, I have not tried with a button but if you can do this it may not work

```
 [btn setBackgroundColor:colour forState:UIControlStateSelected & UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

I have assumed this is StoryBoard, there is no init, initWithFrame so add them if you need them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you have an image:

```
-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

or see if `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` is enough for you.

Comment: I tried playing around with showsTouchWhenHighlighted but it didn't help. I don't want to use setBackgroundImage:forState:. I was in fact trying to use the backgroundColor to not use any image.

Answer (score 2):

I have open-sourced a UIButton subclass, [STAButton](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/blob/master/STAControls/STAControls/Button/STAButton.m), to fill in this gaping functionality hole. Available under the MIT license. Works for iOS 7+ (I have not tested with older iOS versions).

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem I created a Category to handle `backgroundColor` States with `UIButtons`:
[ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS/tree/master/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS)

You can install the category as a [pod](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/ButtonBackgroundColor-iOS/blob/master/README.md).

Easy to use with **Objective-C**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *myButton;

...

[self.myButton bbc_backgroundColorNormal:[UIColor redColor]
                 backgroundColorSelected:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Even more easy to use with **Swift**:

```
import ButtonBackgroundColor

...

let myButton:UIButton = UIButton(type:.Custom)

myButton.bbc_backgroundColorNormal(UIColor.redColor(), backgroundColorSelected: UIColor.blueColor())
```

I recommend you import the pod with:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'ButtonBackgroundColor', '~> 1.0'
```

Using use_frameworks! in your Podfile makes easier to use your pods with Swift and objective-C.

**IMPORTANT**

[**I also wrote a Blog Post with more information.**](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/uibutton-backgroundcolor-for-uicontrolstateselected/)

Answer (score 2):

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if (isHighlighted) {
                alpha = 0.5
            }
            else {
                alpha = 1
            }            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/swordray/UIButtonSetBackgroundColorForState

Add to Podfile using CocoaPods

```ruby
pod "UIButtonSetBackgroundColorForState"
```

**Swift**

```swift
button.setBackgroundColor(.red, forState: .highlighted)
```

**Objective-C**

```m
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change the highlighted/selected button background color by simply using the `setBackgroundImage` method on UIButton and using an image by using this `UIImage(color:)` initializer, like this:

```
btn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .black), for: .highlighted)
```

**Note:**

If you use the `cornerRadius` property for rounded borders you have to set the `clipsToBounds` to `true` so the selected background color will reserve the corner radius value.

Comment: What version of iOS/Swift does this apply to? In iOS15/Swift 5 there doesn't appear to be a UIImage constructor that takes a "color".

Answer (score 1):

Try `tintColor`:

```
_button.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Are you sure it's linked in IB? What do you get if you do `NSLog(@"%@", _button);`?

Comment: This won't work if you're using a `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in Swift to select for button state:

```
func imageWithColor(color:UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Example:

```
    self.button.setImage(self.imageWithColor(UIColor.blackColor()), forState: .Highlighted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop it in and you're good to go:
*proerty can be set in IB, and if no highlighted background is set, background will not change when pressed

```
private var highlightedBackgroundColors = [UIButton:UIColor]()
private var unhighlightedBackgroundColors = [UIButton:UIColor]()
extension UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var highlightedBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return highlightedBackgroundColors[self]
        }

        set {
            highlightedBackgroundColors[self] = newValue
        }
    }

    override open var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return super.backgroundColor
        }

        set {
            unhighlightedBackgroundColors[self] = newValue
            super.backgroundColor = newValue
        }
    }

    override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return super.isHighlighted
        }

        set {
            if highlightedBackgroundColor != nil {
                super.backgroundColor = newValue ? highlightedBackgroundColor : unhighlightedBackgroundColors[self]
            }
            super.isHighlighted = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you won't override
just set two action 
touchDown
touchUpInside

Answer (score 0):

Below `UIIImage` extension will generates image object with specified color parameter.

```
extension UIImage {
    static func imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        tintColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
       }
    }
```

An example usage for a button can be applied for the button object as :

```
setupButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor(displayP3Red: 232/255, green: 130/255, blue: 121/255, alpha: 1.0)), for: UIControlState.highlighted)

setupButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor(displayP3Red: 255/255, green: 194/255, blue: 190/255, alpha: 1.0)), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
extension UIButton {
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0,width: 1.0,height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forUIControlState state: UIControlState) {
        self.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: color), for: state)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 5

For those who don't want to use colored background to beat the selected state

Simply you can beat the problem by using #Selector & if statement to change the UIButton colors for each state individually easily

For Example:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.white  //to reset the button color to its original color ( optionally )
}

@IBOutlet weak var myButtonOutlet: UIButton!{
    didSet{  // Button selector and image here
        self.myButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(systemName: ""), for: UIControl.State.normal)

        self.myButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "checkmark"), for: UIControl.State.selected)



        self.myButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedButton), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }
}

@objc func tappedButton() {  // Colors selection is here
    if self.myButtonOutlet.isSelected == true {

        self.myButtonOutlet.isSelected = false
        self.myButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.white         
    } else {
        self.myButtonOutlet.isSelected = true

        self.myButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.myButtonOutlet.tintColor00 = UIColor.white

    }
}
```