# Change background color of UIButton while highlighted

Tags: uibutton, xcode5

Is there any way to change the background of a uibutton while it is highlighted and then have it revert back to original state?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an image in the utilities panel at the right-side of your screen.

[image]

Or use this code:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```