# how to get the default highlighted color/ state of UIButton in a subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton subclass that does not use a UIImage background, just a background color. One thing i've noticed is that when you set a button's background image, there is a default highlighted state where the button would turn slightly darker when pressed.

Here is my current code.

```
 - (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

With this code,I am not given that default selection state if i only set the background color. I've tried overriding this with `- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted`and setting the darker color of the button, but either I am not getting the color right or theres more to just setting the color.

I'm unsure of how i can mimic that selection state. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted

Answer (score 0):

```
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] UIControlStateHighlighted]; // To set title label color for highlighted state.
```

Comment: i am talking about the entire color of the UIButton, not just the title's color

Comment: I didn't see the link Yameo shared which I think answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by registering events to the button.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown | UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchCancel | UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
```

After you do that, you need to implement both buttonTouchDown: and buttonTouchUp:.

```
    - (void) buttonTouchDown:(UIButton *)sender {
        // button color when it's highlighted
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor red];
    }
```