# Programatically change custom UiButton background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Within my custom `UIButton` class called "ComingHomeButton", I'm not able to change the backgroundcolor

I would like to change it without creating images, but if it is the only way I will have to.

I also want to change the background color every time the button is tapped.

Here is what I have that doesnt work:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.5];
[self setBackgroundColor:color];
```

self refers to my "ComingHomeButton"

Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Checkout UIButton controlstate. You can set up background for various different UIButoonControlState.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted  Take a look at the accepted answer, it probably is the answer you're looking for!

Comment: I want the color to stayed change after the button has been tapped :-(

Comment: that RGB combination maps to pure white... try using some decimal fraction; e.g. "`colorWithRed:(255.0f/255.0f) green:(0.0f/255.0f) blue:(125.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.5`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a counter, and then loop through colors when a button is tapped:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (!counter) {
    counter = 0
    }
    if (counter%3 == 0) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //or whatever custom color you want to use
    } else if (counter%3 == 1) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else if (counter%3 == 2) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    counter++
}
```

and you can add as many colors as you want to loop through. The % denotes the mod function, making sure that when counter is bigger than 2, it will still return a number between 0 and 2.

The number after the % is the number of colors to loop through.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

The following code works fine for adding a button the a given view with a background button. Try using the dot notation instead of the message pass.

Comment: He doesn't want a new Button te be created!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    sender.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];

}

-(UIColor *)randomColor
{
    CGFloat red = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat green= arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat blue= arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];

    return color;
}
```

I did not test the code I am not on my mac but it should work.