# Changing color of button when touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to change the color and image of a button when its pressed. This is what i have

```
 - (IBAction)likeButtonTouched:(UIButton*)sender {
sender.imageView.image = [sender.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[sender setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Like Filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sender setTintColor:secondaryColor];
}
```

This code works in viewDidLoad but in this, the tint color isnt changed but the image is. Anyone know why?

Comment: You can try to take a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted

Comment: Silly question but are you sure that `secondaryColor` has a valid, non-nil value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Override the UIButton's method with the following Method.
Just change the background color of the button when it is in highlighted state.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
      [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

      if (highlighted) {
          self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // whatever color you want
     }
}
```

Comment: there has to be an easier way, no?

Comment: This solution will work, but it is not ideal because OP will have to subclass UIButton just for this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a subclass of a UIButton that does something similar a while ago:

```
@implementation OnTouchHighlightButton

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self addActionSelectors];
}

- (void)addActionSelectors
{
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(onTouchDown) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchDown | UIControlEventTouchDragEnter)];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(onTouchUp) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchDragExit | UIControlEventTouchCancel)];
}

- (void)onTouchDown
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                      duration:0.15
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        self.highlighted = YES;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}

- (void)onTouchUp
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                      duration:0.15
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        self.highlighted = NO;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}

@end
```

You can add whatever you want on the onTouchUp and onTouchDown methods. You can also change the control events that fire these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple does not provide `forState:` setter methods for the tintColor and backgroundColor properties on UIButton, so you will have to use control events. However, you shouldn't have to subclass UIButton.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonToAppearHightlighted:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown | UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonToAppearUnhightlighted:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside | UIControlEventTouchCancel | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)changeButtonToAppearHightlighted:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:self.button]) {
        sender.tintColor = BUTTON_TINTCOLOR_HIGHLIGHTED;
        sender.backgroundColor = BUTTON_BACKGROUNDCOLOR_HIGHLIGHTED;
    }
}

- (void)changeButtonToAppearUnhightlighted:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:self.button]) {
        sender.tintColor = BUTTON_TINTCOLOR_UNHIGHLIGHTED;
        sender.backgroundColor = BUTTON_BACKGROUNDCOLOR_UNHIGHLIGHTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarkBourke doesn't compile? unexpected behavior? nothing happens at all? Please elaborate

Comment: sorry, it complies but the color doesnt change

Comment: what i want to do is, change the color and the image when the button is "selected" i dont want to change the highlight state

Comment: @MarkBourke so this is supposed to act like a toggle or on/off button? If that's the case, you may want to revise your question. "When it's pressed" is somewhat vague.

Comment: i dont see how changing the question will have anything to do with that. i want to change the color of a uibutton image

Comment: "when its pressed" could mean "when you first touch down on the button", "when you release your touch off of the button", "when the button is tapped once" (if it is a toggle button)...

Answer (score -3):

Sorry for last time reply; Some get wrong info.

Here I am updating the answer in Swift 3.0 ; Hope it works well as per your query;

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorChangeBtn: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    colorChangeBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    colorChangeBtn.tintColor = UIColor.cyan
    colorChangeBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "select.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
  }

@IBAction func colorChange(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    sender.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "focus.png"), for: .normal)
  }
```

Comment: `-[UIButton setBackgroundColor:forState:]` and `-[UIButton setColor:forState:]` are not real methods.

Comment: then what about the setting Image, is that also incorrect #n00neimp0rtant.

Comment: yes, because OP is interested in setting `image`, not `backgroundImage`.

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant have you checked now as per the question asked? Because if the answer is correct others can use it. Downvote will let others know that this is wrong answer.