# Swift - UIButton not highlighted while pressed

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I am having a problem when adding a `UIButton` programatically. There is no "tap-animation".

Does anyone know why that occurs and how to fix this? I couldn't find anything on this topic...

```
let weiterButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.setTitle("WEITER", for: .normal)
    v.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 20)
    v.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 75/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1)
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(weiterButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

**Animation I would like to have:**

[Animation](https://streamable.com/63kv6)

Comment: did u try applying colours for states highlighted / pressed ?

Comment: no. I just want the standard tap animation. It seems like it is working when adding a `backgroundImage` but I also want the animation without an `image` ..

Comment: @TejaNandamuri is right. You need to add custom colours of text for highlighted states, e.g. just add this line 
`v.setTitleColor(.red, for: .highlighted)`

Comment: but `backgroundColor` should be changed and not `TitleColor`.

Comment: @AlexSmet I updated my question with a video

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the background color of a UIButton while it's highlighted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted

Comment: got it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `lazy var` instead of `let` because you want to get out of your variable(button). Also, you have to set `UIButton(type: .system)` because you tell that button should have some kind of style.

```
lazy var weiterButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton(type: .system)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.setTitle("WEITER", for: .normal)
    v.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 20)
    v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    // If you want a different color when it is pressed
    v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Hlighlighted image"), for: .highlighted)
    v.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Your image"), for: .normal)
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(weiterButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

Comment: changing it to `lazy var` didn't do anything

Comment: It is weird. Do you have an @objc func?

Comment: yep, which is working just like it should. I am having this problem with other `UIButtons` as well

Comment: Don't you have something wrong in your ViewController?

Comment: You mentioned that other UIButtons don't work as well. Are your Buttons in the same ViewController or it is in another ViewController?

Comment: in another ViewController

Comment: Try to add one more button to the same ViewController.

Comment: Well... You have to set UIButton(type: .system)

Comment: where do I have to set that?

Comment: let v = UIButton(type: .system) Look at my edited post

Comment: that changes `titleColor`  to blue and the it is getting highlighted but that's not what I want

Comment: @Daveloper If you mean that this weak variable is reset to nil, you could wrong, because you don't see other parts of source code.

Comment: @Daveloper Assuming this is declared in a class, the declaration should look like this: `lazy var weiterButton: UIButton = { [weak self] in` to prevent memory leaks.